# Multiple selection in pandas dataframe by DateTimeIndex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetimeindex

I'm trying to select certain rows in a dataframe based on a list. If you set up the index of a dataframe as a DatetimeIndex you can select just by:

```
example_df['2018-12-12']
```

But you can't select multiple dates like this:

```
example_df[['2018-12-12', '2018-12-05']]
```

I know I can do the following, but I don't want to type the whole list in case it was longer:

```
example_df['2018-12-12'] & example_df['2018-12-05'] & ...
```

Also I know I can use the `isin()` method but I want to take advantage of the native date selector in pandas because I belive is faster.

Here is the code:

```
genesis_block_date = pd.to_datetime('01/03/2009 18:15:05 GMT')
end_date = pd.to_datetime('01/03/2029')

# Halving dates
halving_dates = ['November 28, 2012', 'July 9th, 2016', '14 May, 2020']
halving_dates = pd.to_datetime(halving_dates)

approx_block_gen_time = pd.to_timedelta('10m')
date_range = pd.date_range(start=genesis_block_date, end=end_date, freq=approx_block_gen_time)

columns = ['days_until_halving']
df_new_features = pd.DataFrame(index=date_range, columns=columns)
df_new_features[halving_dates] = ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you have a datetime index, but you try to select from it using strings (which it does not contain).

You have to supply a list of datetime objects to the .loc[ ] selection method. pd.to_datetime([list of dates]) gets this job done:

```
example_df.loc[pd.to_datetime(['2018-12-12', '2018-12-05'])]
```

Please bear in mind that you can only select columns by providing a list to the selection:

```
example_df[['2018-12-12', '2018-12-05']]
```

So you get an error, because there are no such columns...

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked. I don't know why but it was obvious that the .loc was expecting the same object type (the index type I mean).

But it's interesting that the regular selector does accept just one date as I said in the OP:
example_df['2018-12-12']